# google chrome console , has a problem in show javascript code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, javascript-debugger

google chrome console , has a problem in show javascript code 
Does not display my codes
Even in debugger , after refresh page or whatever 
js script in my page start with :  `<script type="text/javascript">` 
my file is php and server is xampp

[image: google chrome console , has a problem in show java code]

Comment: That script tag is broken, you mostly need a `src` but you also have an unclosed quote.

Comment: really ?? you for write js code , in script tag use a `src` ?
quote sign lost in post , in code has true

Answer (score 0):

[Syeed Masoud Tayefi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6862811/syeed-masoud-tayefi) indeed you need to add the src to the tag, otherwise the browser not only won't show you the file, neither read it and hence not perform any fuction that has been wrote down. Here is how I do it myself in order to check and debug if need it

```
<body>
    <div> ...whatever goes in here...</div>
    <script src="./functions.js"></script>
</body>
```

Hope my answer help a bit to clarify your question. As You didn't leave any of your code, I can't speak about the unclosed issues, if any.